# How can you have a mismatch between a local npm package and repo though the packages report same version?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just updated Angular 8.2.4 -> 9.1.6 and Typescript 3.4 -> 3.8.3 using

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

I've got a number of module imports that are now breaking. They work if I downgrade to Typescript 3.7 but I need 3.8 for a particular package.

The specific module import error I'm delving into here:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '<project>/pangeav4/node_modules/request'
```

An 'npm ls request' shows request is being used in the dependencies of Angular 9.1.6.

```
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.6
│ └─┬ less@3.11.1
│   └── request@2.88.2 
├─┬ @angular/cli@9.1.6
│ └─┬ universal-analytics@0.4.20
│   └── request@2.88.2  deduped
```

And if I go to my local node_module/@angular_devkit/build-angular/package.json (v 0.901.6), I see the package "less" is a dependency.

However, in the package.json of the github for @angular_devkit/build-angular (v 0.901.6), less is not included at all..

How can it be that my local copy differs from the github if the versions are the same?

I've tried deleting package-lock and node_modules and reinstalling.

I made a new angular project which defaulted to v8 because of the global cli. I figured the issue must be a mismatch between the global and local cli (though the ng update continues and just notes that it is using a temp build for the install). I updated the global cli to 9 and created a new project without the issue.

Once I added the dependencies from the existing project, the issue returned. However, removing those dependences from the package.json, deleting node modules and the lock, and reinstalling did not fix the new project.

Is there something other than package-lock.json that is retaining the install command for whatever package is messing things up?

Angular version info:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.6
Node: 10.18.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.801.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.6
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.6
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.6
@angular/fire                     5.4.2
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.6
@schematics/angular               9.1.6
@schematics/update                0.901.6
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Comment: Did you do it with `ng update`? You might try deleting your node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and running `npm install` again.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I've done that already

Comment: You probably upgraded everything wrong. I would suggest reverting your changes and updating your packaged via the cli. If you do that, angular will make sure all the dependencies are in order.

Comment: I updated using ng update @angular/core@9 @angular/cli@9

Comment: According to what you said, you updated typescript manually. that is where you went wrong. ng update will handle that for you

Comment: Should also just have ran `ng update @angular/core @angular/cli` (without the @9 version call out)

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you might have installed TypeScript manually and messed up some dependency tree. I would try reverting your changes and running the upgrade via `ng update`. FWIW, my 9.1 project has `"typescript": "3.7.5"`

When you run `ng update`, it will give you the summary and then you have to start going through and upgrading things one by one. Usually the first thing you'll have to do it run:

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`. You don't want to specify any version here unless you're targeting something specific. It will grab the latest version by default.

One other good troubleshooting step is to go through their upgrade form to determine what steps you need to take in order to upgrade your project:

https://update.angular.io/

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 10.16.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cdk                      9.2.2
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
@angular/material                 9.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.7
@schematics/angular               9.1.4
@schematics/update                0.901.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Comment: Hey thanks for posting this. so i downgraded typescript to 3.7 earlier and those errors went away. would you mind updating your typescript to 3.8 from 3.7.5 and see if you get the same errors?

Comment: I did actually just go through the process of upgrading to 9.1.6. My TypeScript version remained 3.7.5 through that process. I did switch TypeScript to 3.8 and it still compiled fine. I would recommend sticking with whatever angular ships unless you're after some super specific TS feature

Comment: Yeah I'm using another package that wants typescript 3.8 (breaks with 3.7)

Comment: One thing you might try and generating a fresh project. see if that gives you 3.8 or sticks with 3.7.5. According to what I'm reading, 3.8 should be just fine.

Comment: I just did the update process again and let ng set the version that it wanted. I'm still getting those same errors though

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help. It was a really confusing problem. Turns out they haven't done an npm publish of the github repo